# How to share same instance of a class in different entry-points in webpack output

Tags: javascript, class, object, webpack, scoping

Does importing a class in different entry-point files of webpack create a new instance of the imported class.
Like I want to import a class `AJAX` whose instance needs to be same throughout the project in both the entry-point files.

Right now it is used as a global object but I want to export it as module in the form of a class or object and along with maintaining the same instance in all the files.https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/blob/master/js/ajax.js

This is my webpack config file emitting two different files both having this AJAX object imported.

```
entry: {
    db_search_new: './js/src/db_search.js',
    tbl_structure_new: './js/src/tbl_structure.js'
},
output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'js/dist'),
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:3007/js/dist'
},
```

How can I achieve this using the javascript modules?
Any idea about hot to implement this using singletons in javascript?

Answer (score 3):

As described [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/7556) Webpack has a separate cache for each entry point but you could set your config to cache everything that end in commons.js (if you use splitChunks), so that just one instance is created. Hope it helps.